# Open CV: Problems with cv2.rectangle() method

Tags: python, opencv

Im just trying some things with OpenCV. Once i try to to put a rectangle on my image, I always receive the following  error: **Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'**

This happens while using the following code:

```
!pip install opencv-python

%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("C:/..../.../.../.../.....jpg")[...,::-1]

cv2.rectangle(img,(400,200),(500,500),(0,0,255),20)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Is there anybody who faced the same issue once?

Thanks for your help in advance

Best regards

Sascha

Comment: This issue is coming because there is no image read in `img` variable. Try printing it using imshow and check.

Comment: If you want it in rgb you can also do `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display with matplotlib, the best way to change from BGR to RGB is to use

```
img = cv2.imread("C:/..../.../.../.../.....jpg")

img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

instead of

```
img = cv2.imread("C:/..../.../.../.../.....jpg")[...,::-1]
```

I tried it and it works.